# Get currently displayed application - current using application name in android

Tags: android, android-activity, package-managers

how I can get currently using application name by user programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

This can be taken from string resources because there you set your application name...

Or from package manager:

```
public static CharSequence applicationName(Context context) {
    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager;
    ApplicationInfo appInfo = packageManager.getApplicationInfo("your.package.name", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    return packageManager.getApplicationLabel(appInfo);
}
```

Comment: I need service which get other applications name that currently used ( displayed ) . Not my own app name